# How do I remove the class from the navbar button when a new link is selected [Javascript]

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an active state on my link when clicked, which remains until another link is clicked. I'd like to have the class removed and transferred to the next link when clicked.

Currently it can be toggled on and off on each link.

```js
// navbar toggle for active state
document.getElementById('navbar__list').addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.target.classList.toggle('funcElemStyle');
});
```

```css
.funcElemStyle {
  background: #333;
}
```

Comment: you could try classList.remove and classList.add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of toggle use `.add()` and .`remove()` functions. Run snippet for an example.

```js
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", event=>{
  event.target.classList.remove("red")
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
.red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using javascript to achive this functionality, you can use CSS to achieve the same effect by using `:active`.

for example:

```css
/* Selects the link element. */
a:active {
    color: #4444AA;
}
```

you can also use `:hover` if you want effects when hovered. CSS also allows chaining so if you want an effect to apply when it is hovered over and active, you can use `:active:hover`